# Showing ImageView and TextView in Gallery

Tags: android

How to show TextView and ImageView both in a single Gallery View . I want to show Image title for each image just below it.

Answer (score 4):

Create a custom layout that uses a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` to position your `TextView` and `ImageView`. Then, use that layout with your `SimpleCursorAdapter` that you hand to the `Gallery`.

Comment: Can you post any example explaining that . I am using the images and text from resources folder

Comment: @user467911: I have done little with `Gallery`, but all `AdapterView` subclasses (`Gallery`, `ListView`, `GridView`, etc.) work pretty much the same. Here is a sample project showing a `SimpleCursorAdapter` for a `ListView` with a custom row: http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Database/Constants/ And here is a free excerpt from one of my books that talks about how to override methods on the adapter to further tailor your look: http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf