# Adding text under Gallery images

Tags: android, android-widget

I need to add the filenames under each image in a Gallery, like this:
[image]

The file names need to remain underneath their corresponding images as the user slides those icons horizontally.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Showing ImageView and TextView in Gallery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872136/showing-imageview-and-textview-in-gallery)